# Pass url subpath to Nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, caching, proxy

I'm using Nginx as a reverse proxy for an API. Let's assume that the URL of the API that should be used for the proxy is "https://api.host.com/endpoint"

How can I redirect all request to my Nginx server to that proxy URL?

Here a few examples how it should look like ("proxy.host.com" is the Nginx server):

- https://proxy.host.com -> https://api.host.com/endpoint
- https://proxy.host.com/test/route -> https://api.host.com/endpoint/test/route
- https://proxy.host.com/image.jpg -> https://api.host.com/endpoint/image.jpg

That's how my Nginx config looks at the moment:

```
proxy_cache_path  /var/www/img-cache-test  levels=1:2    keys_zone=STATIC:10m     inactive=24h  max_size=10g;

server {
    server_name proxy.host.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass              https://api.host.com/endpoint;
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_buffering         on;
        proxy_cache             STATIC;
        proxy_cache_valid       200  7d;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `proxy_pass https://api.host.com/endpoint/;` (note the trailing slash) or your URIs will become `/endpointtest/route`, `/endpointimage.jpg` etc. And yes, that means that the "root" request `https://proxy.host.com` will be proxied to `https://api.host.com/endpoint/`.